# download zip file using jquery

Tags: jquery, download

I'm trying to download a zipped directory containing requested files.

```
$.post(`http://${self.location.hostname}/reactiv/download/files.zip?userName=${userName}`,
    requestedFiles,
    function (data, status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            // Code to save ZIP file.
            // data contains the bytes for the zip file
        }
        else {
            alert("couldn't download files.");
            refreshDownloadFileList();
        }
    });
```

Restrictions:

1. I can't do a direct download, since results are determined by both requested files and server side logic.
2. Files are mixed (no text files)
3. Ideal solution can handle GBs of data.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How do I convert that data stream into a physical file?

Every method I used gave me a corrupted zip file.

Comment: is the zip file ok?
is the zip file on the same domain as the script?

Comment: Yes the zip file is okay. I can save the file without issue. Yes we are on the same domain.
On the server side I'm using DotNetZip.Semverd 

When saved on the server, file size (for ex. is 20,656kb). When downloaded, the file size is 37,706kb. I looked at the raw bits using Notepad++. The issue seems to be wrong encoding. Unfortunately I can't fix the encoding issue

On HTML web page,
// I tried other types such as 'application/octet-stream', 'text/plain;charset=utf-8', 
const blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: 'application/zip'
});
// FileSaver
saveAs(blob, 'download.zip');